# Wordpress before save / update member

Tags: members

I have a site that requires to search for lat long information before been saved / updated a member profile, this is searched from google on reverse geolocation through a custom file name location.

I am not looking the function on solve that, I ma looking way on hook the function

Any suggest on how to solve that?

Comment: Hm, are you sure you want to do this _before_ update? Why exactly? It is usually easy in WP inserts to hook right after it happened, but right before is challenging.

Comment: Cause I need user enter some location info and then make a map for all users, then I will need a latlong key pair for display positions on a map

Comment: I am sorry, that doesn't quite explain to me why _before_ rather than _after_ matters. Maybe you could provide your data flow for this step by step?

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this

```
/**
 *  Get City state from zipcode
 */
function rtp_get_city_state($location) {

    $details_url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$location.'&sensor=false';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

    if ($response['status'] != 'OK') {
        return null;
    }

    print_r($response);
}
```

Comment: Sure, I though, my question is no clear, the question is how to hook it before update / save memeber. I have not found that